# Cypress tests for Gatsby failed on GitHub Actions

Tags: shopify, gatsby, cypress, github-actions, contentful

We write Gatsby.js with Contentful and Shopify integration. And we have Cypress tests, that we are running on GitHub Actions.
But I have errors, such

```
  1) Test shopify cart
   Buying only first product
     should open product modal:
 AssertionError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: `[data-test=product-modal]`, but never found it.
  at ensureExistence (http://localhost:8000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:137673:32)
  at Object.ensureElExistence (http://localhost:8000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:137691:12)
  at ensureExistence (http://localhost:8000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:127867:23)
  at onFailFn (http://localhost:8000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:127905:9)
  at tryCatcher (http://localhost:8000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:9065:23)
  at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (http://localhost:8000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:7000:31)
  at Promise._settlePromise (http://localhost:8000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:7057:18)
  at Promise._settlePromise0 (http://localhost:8000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:7102:10)
  at Promise._settlePromises (http://localhost:8000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:7178:18)
  at _drainQueueStep (http://localhost:8000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:3772:12)
  at _drainQueue (http://localhost:8000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:3765:9)
  at Async.../../node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js.Async._drainQueues (http://localhost:8000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:3781:5)
  at Async.drainQueues (http://localhost:8000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:3651:14)
```

Scripts that start test:

```
"test:e2e:ci": "start-server-and-test develop http://localhost:8000 cy:run"
"develop": "gatsby develop",
```

Does anybody have ideas how to fix this?
Coz on the local machine everything is okay...

Comment: Can you render a screenshot or anything? :) The error is telling that an element is not there. You have to find out the state of the page somehow. :)

Comment: It's pity by not, the only I can - to connect tests ti Cypress Hub to check videos.  But in general looks like on CI gatsby doesn't include/build shopify content =(

Comment: You can get screenshots and videos as GitHub Actions artifacts: https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action#artifacts This should help you debug

Comment: But generally, if there's a difference between local and CI builds, the first thing I would look into is if your environment variables are properly set up on both sides

Comment: @RobinMétral Thanks a lot! Just found issue with incorrect Shopify secret on GitHub Secrets

Comment: Happy to help! This has happened to me a lot :P I'll post it as an answer as well so that we can mark this as resolved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should try when there are issues in your CI that you can't reproduce locally is to double check your CI environment, and make sure it closely matches your local machine.

For Gatsby sites, especially when using a plugin that takes secrets (like your Shopify credentials, for example), a common issue is to not have your [environment variables](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/) properly set up in the CI.

Make sure your GitHub repo has the right secrets set up, and that you're providing them to your GitHub actions. Take a look at GitHub's [Creating and storing encrypted secrets](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets) for help.

If you're certain that your environment variables are not the issue, you can debug Cypress CI runs by saving the Cypress screenshots and videos as GitHub Action artifacts. The [official Cypress GitHub Action](https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action) has an [example](https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action#artifacts) of how to do this using GitHub's `actions/upload-artifact`.